# Creating json array in django

Tags: python, arrays, json, django

I am trying to make a json array in django but I am getting error -

```
In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False
```

and my views.py -

```
def wall_copy(request):
    if True:
        posts = user_post.objects.order_by('id')[:20].reverse()
        return JsonResponse(posts)
```

Basically user_post is a model a posts is the object of top 20 saved data. I want to send a json array but I am unable to convert posts into a json array. I also tried serializers but it didnt helped.

I am stuck help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Would this solve your problem?

```
from django.core import serializers
def wall_copy(request):
    posts = user_post.objects.all().order_by('id')[:20].reverse()
    posts_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', posts)
    return JsonResponse(posts_serialized, safe=False)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but now I am unable to get the data. Can you please tell me how can I retrieve the json data...??

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake n the posts=... line. The call to the all() function was missing. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this by using `safe=False`:

```
    def wall_copy(request):
        posts = user_post.objects.all().order_by('id')[:20].reverse()

        return JsonResponse(posts, safe=False)
```

Note that it's not really *unsafe* - you just have to make sure on your own, that what you are trying to return can be converted to JSON.

See [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) docs for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *values* method: http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.x/ref/models/querysets.html#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values. It will produce dict-like representation for objects fields you need.

Comment: Hey I tried it but it did not worked for me. Anyways thanks for the advice, that was something new.